# Increase file size to at least N on windows without race condition

Tags: c, windows, filesize

I am looking for a way to increase the size of a file to at least N bytes in a way that does not suffer from race conditions.

The simple approach, of couse, has a race condition:

```
LARGE_INTEGER large_int;
GetFileSizeEx(handle, &large_int);
if (large_int.QuadPart < N) {
  SetFilePointerEx(handle, N, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
  SetEndOfFile(handle);
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Elaboration on race condition:

The initial file size is zero.
Alice wants to set the size to at least 100.
Bob wants to set the size to at least 200.
It is clear that had ther been no race condition, then when both Alice and Bob have finished, the size of the file must be at least 200.

Assume both Alice and Bob reads the current file size as zero.
Then Bob sees that he needs to increase the size to 200, so he set the size to 200.
Now Alice get to run, and she concludes that 100 is more than zero, which she thinks is the current size, and she then sets the size to 100.

Comment: You'll need to draw a Big Arrow at the place in this code where the race occurs, I don't see it.  In general there is no way to make the file system thread-safe.  Programs need to negotiate access to a file.  Either by explicitly locking the file, by using secondary synchronization through a named mutex or delegate duties to a dedicated server.  A dbase server being the most typical example of that.

Comment: @HansPassant What I was hoping for, was a native system call that could be used or abused to achieve this. I agree that without native support for such a thing, it is hard. You would probably have to resort to mandatory file locking. Note that posix_fallocate() achieves this without race conditions on POSIX systems.

Comment: Note that the posix system call you mention does locking internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it:

```
DWORD protect = PAGE_READONLY;
LARGE_INTEGER large_int;
large_int.QuadPart = desired_minimum_size;
HANDLE map_handle = CreateFileMapping(file_handle, 0, protect, large_int.HighPart, large_int.LowPart, 0);
CloseHandle(map_handle);
```

I wonder what the overhead of doing it this way is compared to the naive approach i mentioned above.

Apparently it is always possible to create a new file mapping object regardless of whether any exist already for that file. The documentation is quite murky in this respect, but I have checked that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use [File Locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking) to make sure that only one process is messing with the file.

Probably something like:

```
check file size, if too small then
  Lock file
  check size again
  set size if needed
  Unlock file
```

Comment: It would be nice to avoid file locking, but it may turn out to be the only way to do it, of course.

Comment: There has to be some locking in any case, there is no atomic CPU instruction which can do it, so you will have to prevent other threads from beating you to the punch. On a single system you might get away with a global kernel lock, but in the case of a shared network drive even that is not going to work, you will need file locking in that case, and a network share that supports it at that.